# NxBRE- Accessing multiple in a RULE

Tags: nxbre

I have two .NET objects, Employee and Department. In .xbre file I need to setup condition as below,

If Employee.EmpID is X and Department.DeptID is Y then do something. So In a given rule, I need to access two objects (employee and department) and validate the condition.

If I use `<ObjectLookup>` then I understand I can pass one object and field (`Employee.EmployeeID` or `Department.DeptID`), can we access both of them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track: you need to use two `<ObjectLookup>` constructs to extract both values and store them in two different variables, something like:

```
<ObjectLookup id="EmployeeID" objectId="Employee" member="EmployeeID" />
<ObjectLookup id="DeptID" objectId="Department" member="DeptID" />
```

Comment: I was doing this way. However, wanted to reconfirm the right approach from you. Thanks.